# Adobe Air FileStream copy jpg from one directory to another

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, jpeg, filestream

I am trying to write a code that can copy a jpg file from one directory to another. What I have in mind is to load the selected jpg into bytes and afterwards write it via writebytes to a designated folder. This is a desktop AIR application.

```
    private function update_treebg(event:MouseEvent):void {
        saveDir = 'structure/' + id + '/bg.jpg';
        file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
        file.browseForOpen("Select an image", [imgFilter]); 
    }

    private function onFileSelected(event:Event):void {
        file.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
        fs.open(event.target as File, FileMode.READ);
        fs.readBytes(bytes);
        fs.close();

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
        loader.loadBytes(bytes);
    }

    private function onFileLoaded(event:Event):void {
        event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);

        var targetFile:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(saveDir);
        fs.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE);
        fs.writeBytes(event.target.bytes, 0, event.target.bytes.length);
        fs.close();
    }
```

Everytime I write the file a corrupted jpg file appears at the designated directory. Did I miss something? If you know of a better way to do this let me know as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this the way you've shown, but there is a much easier way to copy a file using the File classes [copyTo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#copyTo()) method.  Here is an example for your context:

```
private function onFileSelected(event:Event):void {
    var sourceFile:File = event.target as File;
    var targetFile:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(saveDir);

    sourceFile.copyTo(targetFile, true); //true is for overwrite if already exists
}
```

Using copy also makes it so you don't have to load the contents/bytes of the file into memory first, which will make it much faster.

If you don't need to wait around for the copy to finish (or if the file is large) you should use [copyToAsync](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#copyToAsync()) instead, so that your program isn't locked while the copy operation completes.

Comment: This is what i was googling around for. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I can be an idiot sometimes...

```
    private function update_treebg(event:MouseEvent):void {
        saveDir = 'structure/' + id + '/bg.jpg';
        file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
        file.browseForOpen("Select an image", [imgFilter]); 
    }

    private function onFileSelected(event:Event):void {
        file.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
        fs.open(event.target as File, FileMode.READ);
        fs.readBytes(bytes);
        var targetFile:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(saveDir);
        fs.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE);
        fs.writeBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        fs.close();
    }
```

I got it fixed.

Comment: Your answer does not explain anything, and as such is of limited use to future visitors.  Please take a few moments to describe your fix instead of just pasting code.